# TextView shaded corner indicating clickable

Tags: android, styles, textview

When using the stock calendar app, and others including GMail, I have noticed how the TextViews have a light grey underline and a light grey corner to indicate that it is clickable.

[image: Sample image of TextView]

How can I style my own TextViews to look like this? I cannot seem to find anything about this previously so it would be nice to know so I can keep my app inline with the stock Android experience.

I have looked through the source code but cannot figure out how this has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and not an [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)?

Answer (score 0):

That is a Spinner, not a TextView.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: They're actually using a TextView which has the Spinner style applied for it (I think anyway, it worked for me). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!